# Show that the terminal object is unique up to a unique isomorphism

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

I am trying learn category theory from a programmer's perspective. Thus the following may be plain wrong. I want to know if my proof below is OK:

Show that the terminal object is unique upto a unique isomorphism

"Unique up to a unique isomorphism" implies the following:
[Unique up to unique isomorphism means that there's only one isomorphism relating the two isomorphic objects.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473420/what-is-the-difference-between-being-unique-unique-up-to-isomorphism-and-unique/473429)

The terminal object is the object with one and only one morphism coming to it from any object in the category. Or alternatively, $T$ is terminal if for every object $X$ in $C$ there exists a single morphism $X \to T$.

So if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two terminal objects, we need to prove that there is ONLY ONE isomorphism that relates $T_1$ and $T_2$.

By definition, "$T$ is terminal if for every object $X$ in $C$ there exists a single morphism $X \to T$."

Hence there should be a morphism from $T_1$ to $T_2$ and a morphism from $T_2$ to $T_1$ (apart from identity morphisms on $T_1$ and $T_2$).

There cannot be more than one morphism between $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Hence $T_1$ and $T_2$ has a unique up to a unique isomorphism.

Comment: You still need to argue that $T_1 \to T_2$ and $T_2 \to T_1$ are mutual inverses. Hint: What is $Hom(T_i,T_i)$?

Comment: There "should be" a morphism from $T_1$ to $T_2$. That's weak; there **is** exactly one morphism from $T_1$ to $T_2$ as $T_2$ is terminal. But to show this is an isomorphism, one needs to prove that its compositions with the unique morphism from $T_2$ to $T_1$ are identity morphisms.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes as T1 and T2 are terminal there is exactly one morphism: one from T1->T2 and T2->T1, Now T1 and T2 have identity functions and T1->T2, T2->T1 morphism exist, which are inverse of each other. Hence it can be proven that T1 and T2 are isomorhpic. Is this OK?

Comment: Are the morphisms from $T_1$ to $T_2$ and from $T_2$ to $T_1$ really inverses?

Comment: I thought that if there is T1->T2 and T2->T1 it implies that T1 and T2 are isomorphic and the pair of morphisms, one is an inverse of other.

Comment: @Ngm Again, the composition $T_1 \to T_2 \to T_1$ is a map $T_1 \to T_1$. How many such morphisms are there?

Comment: Only one? which is nothing but the identity?

Comment: @Ngm Exactly. So can you finish the argument now? Two objects $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic if and only if there exist morphisms $f : X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$ such that $f \circ g = id_Y$ and $g \circ f= id_X$.

Comment: Got it, I can expand the proof